# Is there in CAML any equivalent of SQL query Prepare

Tags: development, caml

I'm looking for any equivalent of SQL query Prepare in CAML. Could You help me.I need optymalization in CAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no prepared statements with CAML.

The most common optimizations are to reduce the viewfields and the returned rows.